Can I just replace this IC to other working SSD so I can restore data from my dead SSD
I need to recover data from my SSD. I'm just beginner engineering, so I still can't find datasheet about this SSD, and where is the problem from this SSD? I was wondering if I can just move this IC to the other working SSD so I can retrieve my important data. So much memory in here.

Edit: I tried to find a short by using a fluid that can indicate, where a short is. I don't know in English, so I think everyone knows, other than that, I still don't know how to check. Maybe you can give me an advice, what should I check next.

If the data is dear to you, I'd recommend sending it off to a specialist in data recovery.  Doing this yourself with little experience will end badly.

I have twenty years of soldering experience but moving a BGA chip between boards is still not something I'd attempt to do myself even if I had access to a professional reflow oven.

"i try doing find a short using fluid that can showing up where is short is" Sounds like somebody sold you snake oil. You shouldn't put snake oil on the PCB, it will likely only damage it further.

@Lundin Snake oil could be rebranded IPA (the alcohol, not the beer) that is supposed to evaporate quicker close to the short than elsewhere? I've used that to find hotspots before. Generally agree with your comments though.

@MrGerber For that you have to power the damaged board, which is a bad idea in this case since you may escalate the damage. And the professional version of that would be to use a thermal IR camera, not to muck around with isopropyl.

@Lundin Yeah, of course. Agree on both accounts. But OP might not know the first point.

what even suggests there's a short here? Why would a professionally manufactured SSD suddenly fail due to a board short? that makes no sense at all.

Do you even know what's wrong with the SSD? Is it being recognized by your laptop/PC? What have you already tried to recover the data on it? I would say the chances of successfully recovering data by moving the Flash chips to another SSD's PCB are very, very small.

If you want to check for shorts, use a thermal camera


im just beginner engineering


retrive my important data. so much memory in here.


can i just move this ic to other working ssd

It's not a piece of cake. There's a huge risk of having the chip(s) damaged so the best thing you can do is request a data recovery professional's help i.e. send the disk so they do everything for you. It'll be costly, but much cheaper than losing the data for good whilst trying to do the stuff by yourself.

Please close questions like this instead of answering. Thanks

@VoltageSpike the moment I posted my answer, the question didn't actually look like a repair-related question to me as it was something like "Is moving the memory IC to a working SSD a possible way to retrieve the data?". Plus, quite a few experienced users placed comments to direct the OP to find the possibly faulty spot (which means helping to repair to some extent) instead of voting to close.
